# Drain line on outdoor AC unit not draining

Tags: hvac

My Complete HVAC unit is outside, the drain hole at the bottom is not draining any water, water seeps out the side of the unit about halfway way up the unit instead… line must be clogged… how do I get access the the opening which must be inside the unit? Or can I clean it out from the outside, I tried a vacuum, but got nothing out… also there is lots of leaves inside the unit below the fan on what appears to be a drip pan…. Anybody got any answers?

Comment: Pictures and a make/model of your HVAC unit would be very helpful.  With the minimal information provided so far, it's almost impossible to recommend what to do.  There are probably access panels to gain access to the insides to look at the drain line, but can't tell without pictures what your setup is.

Comment: A small snake might work it's way up the drain line, but make sure you turn the power off to the unit before doing so. You don't want it showing up inside the unit and getting caught up in a fan or belt or who knows what. Additionally, no matter what the brand, having it half full of leaves is _not_ going to help.